Loading Css in django template
Using Django template, i made some HTML files and one base.html, while I'm in local, there are zero issues, everything loads perfectly, while I'm production however, the base.html css won't load, everything else loads, images , js, and even the css of other stuff ( i ran collectstatic ) but this particular one doe not load, i load it up using tags  <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static "css/style.css" %} exactly like this in other templates, all the css files are inside a folder called ***/public_html/static/css and in my settings.py, i have this line
STATIC_ROOT = '/somepath/public_html/static'

after running collectstatic, Django put all of my img, css,js and vids and put them inside this folder so :
/somepath/public_html/static/
                            |img/
                            |vid/
                            |css/
                            |js/

what am i doing wrong? why every things load properly including all the img and css but the css of Django templatebase.html  doesn't ?
base.html is the template file that most template extend from it using Django template extend feature.
So far i haven't tried anything special, if i load the css manually, it works, it just that when i extend the html using Django template it doesn't, I'm using Django version 3.x.x however and not the latest one on a domain with cPanel.
Edit: some stuff i forgot to include.
the folder structure:
├── my_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── setting
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── home
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── package
│   ├── templatetags
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── blog_tumb
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   ├── js
│   └── vid
├── templates
│   ├── accounts
│   └── home

Aside from Django and pillow I'm not using any other modules.

Can you provide de structure you have for your django modules?

pls add base.html

cant find base.html in structure

its inside template/home/
the html loads properly, its just the css that of the base html that does not, i wondered if it's a common problem with Django or i did something wrong
